# java installation problem ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

on typing java -version it is giving below error
bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I dont know what to do I want to install hadoop
but I am unable to complete java installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Answer (score 0):

That error generally means that the java package you have is not right type for your system.  Typically this happens when a system of x86 tries to read x64-based files.

Comment: It could be vice versa. He should see whether the file(JAR or class) is not corrupt also in some other system where Java is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Seems some issue with your OpenJDK(default jdk) that comes with ubuntu.
I have hadoop 2 installed - single node cluster on my ubuntu box. You can follow these steps to install Oracle Java 8 which is compatible with Hadoop2(MRv2).
Open terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

then verify

```
java -version
```

and then setup env variables

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

And if you want you can refer to my [blog](http://gettingstartedwithhadoop.blogspot.com/) about setting up Hadoop(MRv1 or MRv2) which contains pointers to some good blogs also.